# Can I define the Negatable interface in Java?

Tags: java, haskell, typeclass

Asking this question to clarify my understanding of type classes and higher kinded types, I'm not looking for workarounds in Java.

---

In Haskell, I could write something like

```hs
class Negatable t where
    negate :: t -> t

normalize :: (Negatable t) => t -> t
normalize x = negate (negate x)
```

Then assuming `Bool` has an instance of `Negatable`,

```hs
v :: Bool
v = normalize True
```

And everything works fine.

---

In Java, it does not seem possible to declare a proper `Negatable` interface. We could write:

```
interface Negatable {
    Negatable negate();
}

Negatable normalize(Negatable a) {
    a.negate().negate();
}
```

But then, unlike in Haskell, the following would not compile without a cast (assume `MyBoolean` implements `Negatable`):

```
MyBoolean val = normalize(new MyBoolean()); // does not compile; val is a Negatable, not a MyBoolean
```

**Is there a way to refer to the implementing type in a Java interface, or is this a fundamental limitation of the Java type system?** If it is a limitation, is it related to higher-kinded type support? I think not: it looks like this is another sort of limitation. If so, does it have a name?

Thanks, and please let me know if the question is unclear!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, no.

You *can* use tricks (as suggested in the other answers) that will make this work, but they do not provide all of the same guarantees that the Haskell typeclass does.  Specifically, in Haskell, I could define a function like this:

```
doublyNegate :: Negatable t => t -> t
doublyNegate v = negate (negate v)
```

It is now known that the argument and return value of `doublyNegate` are both `t`.  But the Java equivalent:

```
public <T extends Negatable<T>> T doublyNegate (Negatable<T> v)
{
    return v.negate().negate();
}
```

doesn't, because `Negatable<T>` could be implemented by another type:

```
public class X implements Negatable<SomeNegatableClass> {
    public SomeNegatableClass negate () { return new SomeNegatableClass(); }
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
       new X().negate().negate();   // results in a SomeNegatableClass, not an X
}
```

This isn't particularly serious for this application, but does cause trouble for other Haskell typeclasses, e.g. `Equatable`.  There is no way of implementing a Java `Equatable` typeclass without using an additional object and sending an instance of that object around wherever we send values that need comparing, (e.g:

```
public interface Equatable<T> {
    boolean equal (T a, T b);
}
public class MyClass
{
    String str;

    public static class MyClassEquatable implements Equatable<MyClass> 
    { 
         public boolean equal (MyClass a, MyClass b) { 
             return a.str.equals(b.str);
         } 
    }
}
...
public <T> methodThatNeedsToEquateThings (T a, T b, Equatable<T> eq)
{
    if (eq.equal (a, b)) { System.out.println ("they're equal!"); }
}
```

(In fact, this is exactly how Haskell implements type classes, but it hides the parameter passing from you so you don't need to figure out which implementation to send where)

Trying to do this with just plain Java interfaces leads to some counterintuitive results:

```
public interface Equatable<T extends Equatable<T>>
{
    boolean equalTo (T other);
}
public MyClass implements Equatable<MyClass>
{
    String str;
    public boolean equalTo (MyClass other) 
    {
        return str.equals(other.str);
    }
}
public Another implements Equatable<MyClass>
{
    public boolean equalTo (MyClass other)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

....
MyClass a = ....;
Another b = ....;

if (b.equalTo(a))
    assertTrue (a.equalTo(b));
....
```

You'd expect, due to the fact that `equalTo` really ought to be defined symmetrically, that if the `if` statement there compiles, the assertion would also compile, but it doesn't, because `MyClass` isn't equatable with `Another` even though the other way around is true.  But with a Haskell `Equatable` type class, we know that if `areEqual a b` works, then `areEqual b a` is also valid.  [1]

Another limitation of interfaces versus type classes is that a type class can provide a means of creating a value which implements the type class without having an existing value (e.g. the `return` operator for `Monad`), whereas for an interface you must already have an object of the type in order to be able to invoke its methods.

You ask whether there is a name for this limitation, but I'm not aware of one.  It's simply because type classes are actually different to object-oriented interfaces, despite their similarities, because they are implemented in this fundamentally different way: an object is a subtype of its interface, thus carries around a copy of the interface's methods directly without modifying their definition, while a type class is a separate list of functions each of which is customised by substituting type variables.  There is no subtype relationship between a type and a type class that has an instance for the type (a Haskell `Integer` isn't a subtype of `Comparable`, for example: there simply exists a `Comparable` instance that can be passed around whenever a function needs to be able to compare its parameters and those parameters happen to be Integers).

[1]: The Haskell `==` operator is actually implemented using a type class, `Eq` ... I haven't used this because operator overloading in Haskell can be confusing to people not familiar with reading Haskell code.

Comment: The first few paragraphs seem to be void because of F-bounded polymorphism: `interface Neg<T extends Neg<T>> { T neg(); }` allows you to invoke `t.neg().neg().neg()` as often as you want, and always get a `T` back: `<T extends Neg<T>> T foo(T t) {
    return t.neg().neg().neg();
  }`. Maybe I just don't quite get what the first few paragraphs are talking about.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - It compiles, but you still don't have the guarantee that on executing the result is the same type as the original value due to the fact that (as long as `T` implements `Neg<T>`) some type other than `T` can also implement `Neg<T>`.  Now, *for this specific example*, I can't see any reason why that could cause a problem, but for other cases (like `Equatable`, where it's expected that if we can call `equals(a,b)` we can also call `equals(b,a)`) that may not work very well.

Answer (score 63):

Actually, yes. Not directly, but you can do it. Simply include a generic parameter and then derive from the generic type.

```
public interface Negatable<T> {
    T negate();
}

public static <T extends Negatable<T>> T normalize(T a) {
    return a.negate().negate();
}
```

You would implement this interface like so

```
public static class MyBoolean implements Negatable<MyBoolean> {
    public boolean a;

    public MyBoolean(boolean a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public MyBoolean negate() {
        return new MyBoolean(!this.a);
    }

}
```

In fact, the Java standard library uses this exact trick to implement `Comparable`.

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    int compareTo(T o);
}
```

Comment: As an aside, in C++ this is known as the "[curiously-recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)".

Comment: I think the better way should be `public interface Negatable<T extends Negatable>`, so that negate can be chained no matter what. Or is there a reason not to do it like that?

Comment: @kutschkem `Negatable` isn't the correct type bound. `public interface Negatable<T extends Negatable<T>>` isn't legal Java

Comment: @Caleth Just tested, totally valid.

Comment: Note that this is *not* exactly equivalent to the given Haskell type class, as the type class *guarantees* that if you have `v :: Negatable t => t` then both `v` and `negate v` are values of type `t`, whereas in Java you could have `Negatable<T> v` but not have `v` actually be of type `t` (I could for instance define `public class X implements Negatable<Integer> { public void negate () { return 1; } }`, which satisfies all the given conditions, but Haskell would disallow this due to not being correctly reflexive as specified in the typeclass.

Comment: @Caleth: Not only is that legal, it's [exactly how Enum is defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

Comment: @Wyzard: Everywhere else, this is known as *F-bounded Polymorphism*.

Comment: It's the wrong kind of polymorphism. It allows you to add *more implementations* of the `Negatable` interface with *same functions*. Haskell's ad-hoc polymorphisms allows you to add *more functions* on *same data*. The one kind scales well if you need more "things" which have the same capabilities (e.g. thousand different GUI-widgets with a couple of methods like `repaint` and `reactOnMouseClick`), the other kind of polymorphism allows you to add more *functions* on same data (starting with `Bool`, you can later tack on `Negatable`, `Monoid`, `Lattice`, `Ring`... etc.). It scales differently.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for generics, plus self typing.  Self typing is the notion of generic placeholder that equates to the class of the instance.

However, self typing doesn't exist in java.

You can get close with generics, but it's clunky:

```
public interface Negatable<T> {
    public T negate();
}
```

Then

```
public class MyBoolean implements Negatable<MyBoolean>{

    @Override
    public MyBoolean negate() {
        //your impl
    }
    
}
```

Some implications for implementers:

- They must specify themselves when they implement the interface, e.g. `MyBoolean implements Negatable<MyBoolean>`
- Extending `MyBoolean` would require one to override the `negate` method again.

Comment: Self typing is probably the name I was looking for. Do you know if there are languages that support self typing natively, without using this trick?

Comment: @zale Typescript has the `this` type, which uses the type of the expression where the function is used.

Comment: You could force implementations to specify themselves through `public interface Negatable<T extends Negatable<T>>`

Comment: @MarDev That doesn't force implementations to specify themselves. Example: `class A implements Negatable<A>{} class B implements Negatable<A> {}`. `B` doesn't specifies itself.

Comment: @zale Scala allows for self-typing using this and mix-ins. Such to self-type a trait: `trait Foo { def name: String} trait Bar { this: Foo => def baz(....)}`

Answer (score 7):

I interpret the question as

#### How can we implement ad-hoc polymorphism using typeclasses in Java?

You *can* do something very similar in Java, but without the type safety guarantees of Haskell - the solution presented below can throw errors at runtime.

Here is how you can do it:

1. Define interface that represents the typeclass

   ```
   interface Negatable<T> {
     T negate(T t);
   }
   ```
2. Implement some mechanism that allows you to *register instances* of the typeclass for various types. Here, a static `HashMap` will do:

   ```
   static HashMap<Class<?>, Negatable<?>> instances = new HashMap<>();
   static <T> void registerInstance(Class<T> clazz, Negatable<T> inst) {
     instances.put(clazz, inst);
   }
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   static <T> Negatable<T> getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
     return (Negatable<T>)instances.get(clazz);
   }
   ```
3. Define the `normalize` method that uses the above mechanism to get the appropriate instance based on the runtime class of the passed object:

   ```
     public static <T> T normalize(T t) {
       Negatable<T> inst = Negatable.<T>getInstance(t.getClass());
       return inst.negate(inst.negate(t));
     }
   ```
4. Register actual instances for various classes:

   ```
   Negatable.registerInstance(Boolean.class, new Negatable<Boolean>() {
     public Boolean negate(Boolean b) {
       return !b;
     }
   });

   Negatable.registerInstance(Integer.class, new Negatable<Integer>() {
     public Integer negate(Integer i) {
       return -i;
     }
   });
   ```
5. Use it!

   ```
   System.out.println(normalize(false)); // Boolean `false`
   System.out.println(normalize(42));    // Integer `42`
   ```

The main drawback is that, as already mentioned, the typeclass instance lookup can fail at runtime, not at compile-time (as in Haskell). Using a static hash map is suboptimal too, because it brings all the problems of a shared global variable, this could be mitigated with more sophisticated dependency injection mechanisms. Automatically generating typeclass instances from other typeclass instances, would require even more infrastructure (could be done in a library). But in principle, it implements ad-hoc polymorphism using typeclasses in Java.

Full code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

class TypeclassInJava {
  
  static interface Negatable<T> {
    T negate(T t);

    static HashMap<Class<?>, Negatable<?>> instances = new HashMap<>();
    static <T> void registerInstance(Class<T> clazz, Negatable<T> inst) {
      instances.put(clazz, inst);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> Negatable<T> getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
      return (Negatable<T>)instances.get(clazz);
    }
  }

  public static <T> T normalize(T t) {
    Negatable<T> inst = Negatable.<T>getInstance(t.getClass());
    return inst.negate(inst.negate(t));
  }

  static {
    Negatable.registerInstance(Boolean.class, new Negatable<Boolean>() {
      public Boolean negate(Boolean b) {
        return !b;
      }
    });
  
    Negatable.registerInstance(Integer.class, new Negatable<Integer>() {
      public Integer negate(Integer i) {
        return -i;
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(normalize(false));
    System.out.println(normalize(42));
  }
}
```